# Unable to access facebook form leads

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am unable to access Facebook leads by form ID.
When I call this,

```
curl -G \
  -d 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  -d 'fields=created_time,id,ad_id,form_id,field_data' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/<FORM_ID>/leads
```

I am getting this error message like this

> "message":"(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app
> secret proof or an app token"

I already have approved pages_show_list, pages_manage_ads, leads_retrieval these permission. Also App is in live mode.

Do i need any other facebook permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send your app id e app secret to retrieve that. u can see that in app's page on facebook dev.
-d "app_secret=<YOUR_APP_SECRET>"

Comment: Is there a way to set the required permissions using a GET request?